# Need help creating the trim from dereks shoe tutorial

Tags: modeling

Im trying to follow dereks shoe tutorial and so far everything has been pretty easy but when I try creating the trim from the existing sole this is what I get. When i try to rewatch what derek did it look s like it almost sticks to the sock model.

[image]

[image]

Here is the tutorial link https://youtu.be/DncP3mKJB2M?t=3424

and the blend file https://we.tl/t-FBdvjDQ1Or

Comment: pls add at least a link to the tutorial with time (where the issue happened) so we can see at least what he did. And if you really wanna help us (to help you), you should include your blend file so we also see/know what you did.

Comment: Hi Chris, Thank you

I just updated the post with the tutorial link and blend file.

Here is the tutorial link https://youtu.be/DncP3mKJB2M?t=3424

and the blend file https://we.tl/t-FBdvjDQ1Or

Comment: oh, the file is gone